# Authentication issue with KMS Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, authentication, curl, encryption

I am new to hadoop KMS and i have started KMS with hadoop. Now I try to run this curl command

```
curl -i --header "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --user hdfs:hdfs -X GET http://192.168.23.199:16000/kms/v1/keys/names
```

hdfs is my hadoop user and has hdfs password.

When I run this curl command I get following response

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 WWW-Authenticate:
>   PseudoAuth Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00
>   GMT; HttpOnly Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 997

Here are my kms-site.sml contents

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.key.provider.uri</name>
    <value>kms://http@192.168.23.109:16000/kms</value>
    <description>
      URI of the backing KeyProvider for the KMS.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.keystore.JavaKeyStoreProvider.password</name>
    <value>none</value>
    <description>
      If using the JavaKeyStoreProvider, the password for the keystore file.
    </description>
  </property>

  <!-- KMS Cache -->
<property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.cache.enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>
      Whether the KMS will act as a cache for the backing KeyProvider.
      When the cache is enabled, operations like getKeyVersion, getMetadata,
      and getCurrentKey will sometimes return cached data without consulting
      the backing KeyProvider. Cached values are flushed when keys are deleted
      or modified.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.cache.timeout.ms</name>
    <value>600000</value>
    <description>
      Expiry time for the KMS key version and key metadata cache, in
      milliseconds. This affects getKeyVersion and getMetadata.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.current.key.cache.timeout.ms</name>
    <value>30000</value>
    <description>
      Expiry time for the KMS current key cache, in milliseconds. This
      affects getCurrentKey operations.
    </description>
  </property>

<!-- KMS Audit -->

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.audit.aggregation.window.ms</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>
      Duplicate audit log events within the aggregation window (specified in
      ms) are quashed to reduce log traffic. A single message for aggregated
      events is printed at the end of the window, along with a count of the
      number of aggregated events.
    </description>
  </property>

  <!-- KMS Security -->

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.type</name>
    <value>simple</value>
    <description>
      Authentication type for the KMS. Can be either &quot;simple&quot;
      or &quot;kerberos&quot;.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
    <value>${user.home}/kms.keytab</value>
    <description>
      Path to the keytab with credentials for the configured Kerberos principal.
    </description>
  </property>

    <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
    <value>${user.home}/kms.keytab</value>
    <description>
      Path to the keytab with credentials for the configured Kerberos principal.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>HTTP/localhost</value>
    <description>
      The Kerberos principal to use for the HTTP endpoint.
      The principal must start with 'HTTP/' as per the Kerberos HTTP SPNEGO specification.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.kerberos.name.rules</name>
    <value>DEFAULT</value>
    <description>
      Rules used to resolve Kerberos principal names.
    </description>
  </property>
  <!-- Authentication cookie signature source -->

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.signer.secret.provider</name>
    <value>random</value>
    <description>
      Indicates how the secret to sign the authentication cookies will be
      stored. Options are 'random' (default), 'string' and 'zookeeper'.
      If using a setup with multiple KMS instances, 'zookeeper' should be used.
    </description>
  </property>

  <!-- Configuration for 'zookeeper' authentication cookie signature source -->

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.signer.secret.provider.zookeeper.path</name>
    <value>/hadoop-kms/hadoop-auth-signature-secret</value>
    <description>
      The Zookeeper ZNode path where the KMS instances will store and retrieve
      the secret from.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.signer.secret.provider.zookeeper.connection.string</name>
    <value>192.168.23.199:2181</value>
    <description>
      The Zookeeper connection string, a list of hostnames and port comma
      separated.
    </description>
  </property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.signer.secret.provider.zookeeper.auth.type</name>
    <value>none</value>
    <description>
      The Zookeeper authentication type, 'none' or 'sasl' (Kerberos).
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.signer.secret.provider.zookeeper.kerberos.keytab</name>
    <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/kms.keytab</value>
    <description>
      The absolute path for the Kerberos keytab with the credentials to
      connect to Zookeeper.
    </description>
  </property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.kms.authentication.signer.secret.provider.zookeeper.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>kms/#HOSTNAME#</value>
    <description>
      The Kerberos service principal used to connect to Zookeeper.
    </description>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually end up doing is passing the user information in the curl command if you are not using kerberos.
The curl looks something like.

`curl -k http://localhost:16000/kms/v1/keys/names?user.name=hdfs`

Comment: this answer helped lots!